# Symbol.WPAN.Bluetooth example that transfers data

Tags: c#, visual-studio, bluetooth, motorola-emdk

I am trying to use Symbol.WPAN.Bluetooth that comes with the EMDK for Symbol devices.

Does anyone happen to have a working example that transfers data?

Symbol's example just pairs the devices.  (They apparently think that transfering data is not really needed in a Personal Area network example.)

Anyway, I know this is a long shot, but if anyone has gotten this to work I would love to see some code.

This is what I have tried.  I have one device press button1 and another device press button2.  The read value is always a zero length byte array.

```
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Symbol.WPAN;
using Symbol.WPAN.Bluetooth;

namespace SmartDeviceProject1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Bluetooth bluetooth = new Bluetooth();
            if (bluetooth.IsEnabled != true)
            {
                bluetooth.Enable();
                bluetooth.RadioMode = BTH_RADIO_MODE.BTH_DISCOVERABLE_AND_CONNECTABLE;
            }

            RemoteDevice connectedDevice = null;
            foreach (RemoteDevice remoteDevice in MakeEnumerable(bluetooth.RemoteDevices))
            {
                if ((remoteDevice.Name == "WM_Dan")  && (remoteDevice.IsPaired == false))
                {
                    remoteDevice.Pair();
                    connectedDevice = remoteDevice;
                }
            }

            string test;
            test = "Testing this out";
            ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
            byte[] encTest = encoding.GetBytes(test);


            if (connectedDevice != null)
            {
                connectedDevice.WriteTimeout = 20000;
                connectedDevice.Write(encTest);
            }


        }

        public static IEnumerable<RemoteDevice> MakeEnumerable(RemoteDevices devices)
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < devices.Length; i++)
            {
                yield return devices[i];
            }
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Bluetooth bluetooth = new Bluetooth();

            if (bluetooth.IsEnabled != true)
            {
                bluetooth.Enable();
                bluetooth.RadioMode = BTH_RADIO_MODE.BTH_DISCOVERABLE_AND_CONNECTABLE;
            }

            RemoteDevice connectedDevice = null;
            foreach (RemoteDevice remoteDevice in MakeEnumerable(bluetooth.RemoteDevices))
            {
                if ((remoteDevice.Name == "WM_Dan2") && (remoteDevice.IsPaired == false))
                {
                    remoteDevice.Pair();
                    connectedDevice = remoteDevice;
                }
            }

            string test;
            test = "Testing this out";
            ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
            byte[] encTest = encoding.GetBytes(test);
            byte[] encTest2;
            string test2;

            if (connectedDevice != null)
            {
                connectedDevice.ReadTimeout = 20000;
                encTest2 = connectedDevice.Read(encTest.Length);
                test2 = encoding.GetString(encTest2, 0, encTest2.Length);
                MessageBox.Show(test2);
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Vaccano. Did you actually tried it? Has it worked? I tried it with out success.

Comment: I was never able to make it work.  Because it is a proprietary bluetooth stack (StoneStreet) you are on your own.  StoneStreet will not talk to you unless you hire them, and Symbol's libraries seem to only be intended to work with printers and headsets (etc).  We had to send our data to a central server and then re-download it to the target device.  Very frustrating, but Symbol/Motorola got in bed with StoneStreet and there is nothing you can do if your device has that stack.  (If you are lucky enough to have the Microsoft stack there are lots of frameworks out there that make this easy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I gave up on using the built in com port connection and opened a SerialPort object on the connection.

```
SerialPort sp = new SerialPort();
sp.PortName = "COM" + connectedDevice.LocalComPort.ToString();
sp.BaudRate = 9600;
sp.DataBits = 8;
sp.Parity = Parity.None;
sp.StopBits = StopBits.One;

sp.Open();
sp.Open();
sp.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(sp_DataReceived);
sp.ErrorReceived += new SerialErrorReceivedEventHandler(sp_ErrorReceived);
sp.WriteLine(textBoxSend.Text);
```

I also found that even though their docs said that LocalComPort was auto assigned, this was not always the truth.  It was best to use their BTExplorer to set it first.

As well, there OpenComPort would work in situations where is should not -- using Reflector it is pretty obviously wrong.  There are checking the return of `::CreateFile("COM" + port...)`  against 0 instead of -1 (`INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`)

Comment: Bless you for posting this.  I had given up.  I will try this code out and hopefully I can get some sort of communication to happen...

Comment: Just saw this was still hanging around.  I will try to check it out soon and see if it works.

Comment: I am using an MC75 and run the example code from Motorola the same as you did.  For me it errors out at the PairRemoteDevice() first line,  m_Bluetooth.RemoteDevices[selectedDeviceIndex].LocalComPort = m_Bluetooth.LocalComPorts[0];  the localcomports array ends up empty.  Gonna give up on this soon.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this can ever help anyone, but here is an old piece of code that I wrote a few years back.

You'll have to clean it up so that it works for your application. My app had a TextBox control that it read from and logged errors to a Global class. Change that to work with what you have, and it should basically be good.

```
static class Scanner {

  const string _CODEFILE = "Scanner.cs - Scanner::";
  static int _baud = 9600;
  static int _bits = 8;
  static string _dataIn = null;
  static string _port = "COM1";
  static Parity _parity = Parity.None;
  static StopBits _stop = StopBits.One;
  static SerialPort _com1 = null;
  static TextBox _textbox = null;
  public enum ControlType { None, BadgeID, PartNumber, SerialNumber, WorkOrder };
  static ControlType _control;

  public static bool Available { get { return ((_com1 != null) && (_com1.IsOpen)); } }

  public static bool Close {
    get {
      if (_com1 == null) return true;
      try {
        if (_com1.IsOpen) {
          _com1.Close();
        }
        return (!_com1.IsOpen);
      } catch { }
      return false;
    }
  }

  public static string Open() {
    const string na = "Not Available";
    if (_com1 == null) {
      string reset = Reset();
      if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(reset)) return reset;
    }
    try {
      _com1.Open();
      return (_com1.IsOpen) ? null : na;
    } catch (Exception err) {
      return err.Message;
    }
  }

  static void ProcessData(string incoming) {
    _dataIn += incoming;
    if ((_control != ControlType.None) && (_textbox != null)) {
      bool ok = false;
      string testData = _dataIn.Trim();
      switch (_control) {
        case ControlType.BadgeID:
          if (testData.Length == 6) {
            if (testData != BarCode.LOGOFF) {
              Regex pattern = new Regex(@"[0-9]{6}");
              ok = (pattern.Matches(testData).Count == 1);
            } else {
              ok = true;
            }
          }
          break;
        case ControlType.PartNumber:
          if (testData.Length == 7) {
            Regex pattern = new Regex(@"[BCX][P057][0-9]{5}");
            ok = (pattern.Matches(testData).Count == 1);
          }
          break;
        case ControlType.SerialNumber:
          if (testData.Length == 15) {
            Regex pattern = new Regex(@"[BCX][P057][0-9]{5} [0-9]{4} [0-9]{2}");
            ok = (pattern.Matches(testData).Count == 1);
          }
          break;
        case ControlType.WorkOrder:
          if (testData.Length == 6) {
            Regex pattern = new Regex(@"[0-9]{6}");
            ok = (pattern.Matches(testData).Count == 1);
          }
          break;
      }
      if (ok) {
        _textbox.Text = testData;
        _textbox.ScrollToCaret();
        _dataIn = null;
      }
    }
  }

  static string Reset() {
    if (_com1 != null) {
      try {
        if (_com1.IsOpen) {
          _com1.DiscardInBuffer();
          _com1.Close();
        }
      } catch (Exception err) {
        return err.Message;
      }
      Global.Dispose(_com1);
      _com1 = null;
    }
    try {
      _com1 = new SerialPort(_port, _baud, _parity, _bits, _stop);
      _com1.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(Serial_DataReceived);
      _com1.Open();
    } catch (Exception err) {
      return err.Message;
    }
    return null;
  }

  public static void ScanSource(ref TextBox objTextBox, ControlType objType) {
    _textbox = objTextBox;
    _control = objType;
    _dataIn = null;
  }

  static void Serial_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e) {
    ProcessData(_com1.ReadExisting());
  }

  public static void Settings(string ComPort, int BaudRate, Parity ParityValue, int Bits, StopBits StopBit) {
    _port = ComPort;
    _baud = BaudRate;
    _parity = ParityValue;
    _bits = Bits;
    _stop = StopBit;
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// Closes the COM Port
  /// COM Port routines are ready to add as soon as I am
  /// </summary>
  static bool ComPortClose {
    get {
      if (_com1 == null) ComPortReset();
      return ((_com1 == null) ? true : _com1.IsOpen ? false : true);
    }
    set {
      if (_com1 == null) ComPortReset();
      else if (_com1.IsOpen) {
        _com1.DiscardInBuffer();
        _com1.Close();
      }
    }
  }
  /// <summary>
  /// Opens the COM Port
  /// </summary>
  static bool ComPortOpen {
    get {
      if (_com1 == null) ComPortReset();
      return (_com1 == null) ? false : _com1.IsOpen;
    }
    set {
      if (_com1 == null) ComPortReset();
      if ((_com1 != null) && (!_com1.IsOpen)) _com1.Open();
    }
  }
  /// <summary>
  /// Initialized the Serial Port on COM1
  /// </summary>
  static void ComPortReset() {
    if ((_com1 != null) && (_com1.IsOpen)) {
      _com1.Close();
      _com1 = null;
    }
    try {
      _com1 = new SerialPort("COM1", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
    } catch (IOException err) {
      Global.LogError(_CODEFILE + "ComPortReset", err);
    }
  }

}
```